# Conjugation of "sparire"

Tags: verbs

I was wondering about the conjugation of the verb "sparire" (to disappear). I have the book "Verbi in tasca", and noticed there that, for instance the passato prossimo is "hanno sparito". But when I did a web check I noticed that far far more often the passato prossimo is given as "sono sparito". Are both acceptable? Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I was intrigued from your web check, and wanted to test it myself. I was surprised when I found this page: http://verbi.woxikon.it/it/sparire that is completely wrong!

Comment: Would you mind indicating the page of the book where you found the verb? Is it possible that you confused "sparire" with "spargere"?If you refer to the list at the end of the book it does show an example (in this case "capire" at page 11) but it also shows the auxiliary verb to use ("essere" in this case) and you need to use that auxiliary not the one in the example.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, the auxiliary verb for *sparire*, as for most intransitive verbs, is *essere* (as can be checked in any real [dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sparire/)), so the passato prossimo is *sono sparito*, *sei sparito*, *è sparito*, *siamo spariti*, *siete spariti*, *sono spariti* (mind the fact that the past participle agrees for its number, singular/plural, with the subject: *sparito* vs. *spariti*).

I don't know that *Verbi in tasca* book, but if this is not an occasional “bug”, the book looks less than useless.

Comment: Some verbs admit both *essere* and *avere*, with slight difference of meaning, for instance *correre*. But *sparire* definitely has *essere*.

Comment: Maybe *ho sparito* is a meridionalism similar to *sono imparato*? (I don't really know, I never lived more south than Tuscany and those forms make me shiver, but it fits the mold)

Comment: No, @DenisNardin, I don't really think so, in this particular case. But there indeed are some intransitive (in standard Italian) verbs used, locally or jocularly, as transitive, such as *scendimi le chiavi*, i.e., *mandami giù le chiavi*. (No worries, Denis, nothing to shiver about: linguistic phenomenons are fascinating things to be studied, even in ourselves, not ugly stuff to be wary of.)

Comment: For what concerns the question it could be a simple misunderstanding on how to use the book as the edition I have seen does not conjugate the verb "sparire". It rather uses "capire" as an example (that the book calls model) and it does specify the auxiliary "essere" in the verbs list. In the notes (page 130) the book shows "sono sparito/a". Unless the OP has a different edition with a typo...

Comment: @DenisNardin *sono imparato* does not exist in southern dialects... *mi hanno imparato* is the "correct" form and means *they teached me*. But the auxiliary is always *avere*.